# MobaXterm: How to see previous commands' terminal output while still being in VIM? (Equivalent of 'Shift + Page Up' in PuTTY)

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, putty, mobaxterm

What I want (which is possible in PuTTY):

1) Login to a machine (using PuTTY)

2) `$ cat /some/file`

[contents of the /some/file shown on screen]

3) `$ vim`

4) Press Shift + Page Up

Result: I can see [contents of the /some/file ] and everything else that was shown on the screen before I entered `vim`.

Now if I try the same thing in Mobaxterm, which is another terminal application on Windows, I don't get to see the output of the previous commands; it only scrolls the file that I opened in `vim` which is not what I want.

I tried to `echo $TERM` from both PuTTY and Mobaxterm, and they both show `xterm` as the output, so I'm not sure what's different in PuTTY.

Comment: Can someone please add mobaxterm to the list of tags? It seems I need 300+ points for it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to **suspend** the running command, usually by typing `control-Z`. You should then be back in the shell. Give the `fg` command to return and bring the command back to the foreground again.

Comment: I've had [bad experiences](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5290/vim-wont-return-to-foreground#comment8096_5290) when doing this.  My advice: Never background Vim; just use `:shell`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that another way is to send the command ":!" to vim. Then, you will view back the terminal, and would be able to see previous commands, until you type "enter" or a new VIM command. Then vim would come back.
Enjoy !
Gilles.

Comment: Or just run `:shell`, which is more readable.  Are those equivalent?